# DNN - Add or create a Role in DotNetNuke with SQL

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

I need to add a new DNN role in SQL.

If I add a new record to the `dbo.roles` table, it does not seem to create the role in the Security Roles page

domain.com/Admin/SecurityRoles.aspx

I tried a `INSERT` command into `dbo.Roles` and also the `AddRole` stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Adding records through SQL is typically not recommended, it would be better off using the RoleController and the API in DNN.

That being said, you might just need to clear the Cache on your site after doing it in SQL to get the roles populated.